# System Communication: Avoiding Including a Large "HAS-A" Hierarchy Which Isn't Used

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, class-design

The situation:

**System A**

Huge, complicated system.  Uses an important Message object with many other Message objects attached, many of which have further Message objects attached.  In total, this is about twenty different objects.

Due to awkward timing with releases and introduction of code churn, System A cannot have its Message object hierarchy touched.

**System B**

Needs to use the same important Message object to communicate with System A to make use of one of its services.  However, since the messages it will send off are going to be invariable, it only uses a very small portion of the Message object hierarchy.

The Question:

How could I allow System B to make use of the important Message object without (a) touching System A, or (b) including a hierarchy of nearly twenty objects, almost none of which are used at all?  Is there a more advanced Design Pattern which could be put to use in this scenario?

Comment: In what way does A provide its hierarchy to B?  Is it a library that the developers of A distribute, or do you have to build up your own because it's in some other language?

Comment: The hierarchy itself isn't exposed (although I have full access to the source).  B interacts with A through an external integration project, which is really just an interface from B's perspective.

Comment: Okay, so library-ish then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up solving this was to go as "bare-bones" and REST-like as possible.

System A has a few functions that don't take in any message objects; rather they accept the minimum amount of data to create message objects of their own, then make use of those.  System A accepts this data as http.

System B has, as a result of this, a bit of hard-coding involved.  Each of the values for a particular call to System A are tossed into an anonymous object, which is then converted into a URL parameter to make a REST call.

Total code count is less overall, and System B doesn't have a massive, mostly useless object hierarchy copied from System A.

Answer (score 1):

Use Facade (or possibly Adapter) to create your own internal interface into the message system, and wrap it around & hide the external message classes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

- At test time, this makes it easy to stub or mock, because you only have to make fakes for your facade.
- At run time, the facade can interact with the real, complicated, redundant heirarchy transparently. You decouple your code from the external implementation.